# Google sheets API sorting by date

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using nodejs with google sheets API and I'm trying to sort data by column with date string that looks like this: 'dd.mm', for example '01.03'. Currently I'm trying to do it by using batchUpdate, but it doesnt work. It sorts by day, 01 is first, 02 is second etc... My request looks like this:

```
await googleSheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
    spreadsheetId,
    requestBody: {
      requests: [
        {
          sortRange: {
            range: {
              sheetId,
              startRowIndex,
              endRowIndex,
              startColumnIndex,
              endColumnIndex,
            },
            sortSpecs: [
              {
                dimensionIndex,
                sortOrder,
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  });
```

How can I make google sheets API see the columns as dates, not as strings? Because I assume thats where the problem is, the date string is sorted like a normal string.

Answer (score 0):

Format the range to date format of `day.month` in your Google Sheets.

1. Highlight column or range you want to format.
2. Click **Format** Tab -> **Number** -> **Custom number format**.
3. In the text box, insert this value: `d"."m`.
4. Click **Apply**.

**Step by step example:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Google Sheets can now recognize the data as date, you can sort it now using the API.

**Example:**

[image]

**Request:**

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "sortRange": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": 0,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 13,
          "endColumnIndex": 1
        },
        "sortSpecs": [
          {
            "sortOrder": "ASCENDING",
            "dimensionIndex": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [Custom date formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?#zippy=%2Ccustom-date-formatting)